# If I name my child Mathematics, will I become the father of Mathematics?

Tags: meaning, nouns, sentence, capitalization

Firstly, I'm a male.

Secondly, this was a troll but I took it seriously:

1. As a proper noun (the child), yes.
2. As a (?) noun, no.

I'm not a grammarian, so my reasoning maybe flawed. I am looking for the correct answer to this question.

**Edit:**

It was an audio, so ignore the capitalisation and punctuation. If it does depend on such factors then you shall include it in your answer.

Comment: The term you're looking for in 2 is *common noun*. (Additionally, the common noun "mathematics" happens to be an *abstract noun*.) As far as grammar is concerned, you can be the father of any noun at all. As far as semantics is concerned, there is no way for me to end this sentence in anything that is not painfully self-evident.

Comment: Yes, you would then be the "father of Mathematics".  Until your child strangled you in your sleep.

Comment: Initially, I thought of putting "common" in place of "?" but I was not sure. That was the answer I gave to my friend, and thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be the father of Mathematics, but not the father of mathematics.

Consider naming the baby Authorized Personnel Only.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you're male or female makes no difference.

- Proper nouns are capitalized: *Meet my daughter, Mathmatics*.
- Common nouns are not: *My kid is great at mathmatics*.

(And *of course* you're looking for the correct answer!)

Comment: ... and the correct spelling?

Comment: Of you’re a female it’s quite a bit harder to be the father...